# It won't show name from parent table, only number or id

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, field, field-names

This is my query. It show results but instead of name of the day it shows only number or id. How to change it?

```
SELECT challenger, challenged, day_id, date_match, CONCAT(term_start,' - ',term_end) 
AS term FROM barbara_schedule 
INNER JOIN barbara_days ON barbara_schedule.day_id = barbara_days.id_day 
ORDER BY date_match, term_start ASC
```

Comment: Your query will show only the columns that you include on the SELECT.

Comment: You need to show us the structure first. I guess you have a field called `day_name` so SELECT it as well. But I only can guess. Also select with alias name cos you might have same field names in both tables. Again, I only can guess without seeing the structure.

Comment: Thank you!! it is working! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only selecting day_id (from the table which I think also contains the actual day).

Add the *name of the day* column name to your query.

Comment: If you posted your structure we could change your query for you